# Paste document files in javascript

Tags: javascript, file, clipboard, paste, clipboarddata

I'd like to paste file to server from client desktop using javascript. 
So I added a listener on paste event:

```
document.addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
        var files = {};
        if(window.clipboardData){ // IE
            files = window.clipboardData.files;
        }
        else {
            files = e.clipboardData.files;
        }
        //...some functions using files
});
```

Event fires correctly but the problem is - e.clipboardData.files has always length of 0. I'm using ctrl+c on my desktop's .docx file. Am I missing something? My browsers are Firefox Quantum 57 and Google Chrome 60 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Can you post a (non) working snippet ? If you [edit] (or create an answer without actually post it) your post with a snippet you'll be able to test it. It works on my browser.

Comment: This is not possible using JavaScript. Http(s) is not the same as ftp protocol. In order to transfer the object from the client to the server you will need to use a different approach. Such as wrapping the the serialized object into a ajax or restful call and posting it to the server via an api or use a server side scripting language such as PHP, Node.js, WebAPI interface. There are a number of different js frameworks to support this type of communication such as angularjs, jquery, backbone etc. Security within the browser will prevent this type of transfer.

Comment: @SergeK. Well, the part not working is explained under my code - files is empty array, and I wanted some copied files in it.

Comment: @rlcrews I know that I can't copy file with just a javascript. I'm using ajax to sent it to java server. But it's not a case. I can't use java to react on paste event. The only option is js/jQuery/extJs 4.2.5. In extJs documentation i found no solution for this problem, jQuery has it's own "paste" event and javascript "paste" seems to be exactly the thing I want. The question is - why files didn't appeared in clipboardData. It takes only special kind of files? I don't know...:(

Comment: @Seric Gotcha I miss read your question. Looking at the MDN documentation is states the data transfer object is normally set using setData(format, data) Maybe you aren't invoking the function fully? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData

Comment: @Seric I meant something that we can live test here, using the `[<>]` button (or CTRL+M) when you [edit] your post. Because, as I said, it is working for me so the code posted here is not the root cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is useful for users to be able to use clipboard keyboard shortcuts such as <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. Chromium exposes read-only files on the clipboard as outlined below. This triggers when the user hits the operating system's default paste shortcut or when the user clicks **Edit** and then **Paste** in the browser's menu bar. No further plumbing code is needed.

```js
document.addEventListener("paste", async e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!e.clipboardData.files.length) {
    return;
  }
  const file = e.clipboardData.files[0];
  // Read the file's contents, assuming it's a text file.
  // There is no way to write back to it.
  console.log(await file.text());
});
```